# VBA Excel Table Formula reference

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to construct a long excel TABLE formula, using VBA and inject it into a new column of the table.

I can do it with a long winding method by referencing the "Name" property of each column. just wondering if there is a quicker syntax to referencing them?

e.g. a property that can give me the string :

```
  Table1[column1]
```

without me referencing to:

```
with Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Str = .DisplayName & "[" & .ListColumns(1).Name & "]"
end with
```

Comment: I'm not saying there's definitely not one there, but I've never come across it. Use the Watches pane of the VBE to examine the properties and see what you can find.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. Are you trying to put the same formula in every column of the table? Do you want to put the formula in every row of a specific column? Or in a new column that has just been added to the table?